# JMeter: How to make the referer field dynamic based on the situation

Tags: jmeter

Apart from the Home page Suppose there are 2 pages i.e page A ,Page B , first step user have to login, then if that user have the permission to view page Page A ,Page B then he can go to those page else on clicking those page name from the top navigational bar user will remain in the home page.

1 login

2 Home [If Login Successful]

|

Check if have permission to view ---------  Logout

|Yes

2 Page A

|

Check if have permission to view Page B  ---------  Logout

|Yes

3 Page B

|

4 logout

Suppose there are 3 users ,i.e user 1 , user 2 and user 3. Now User 1 have the permission to view both page A , page B but user 2 have the permission to view only page A and user 3 do not have the permission to view any of this two pages.

i have used assertion under the page A sampler , page B sampler to check weather correct threads are accessing this pages or not that is system is allowing only the authorized person or not.

in the thread group i have opted if error occur then " stop thread " , thats why if any thread fail to assert then it is not getting counted in the future , thats why in the logout sampler only 1 thread is showing, and that thread is for user 1 because this user have the permission to view both page A ,B . and user 2 and 3 are not considered as they have fail assertion in the previous stages. so is there any way out that in the logout page i can send all those thread which have cleared the login section successfully irrespective of there view page permission.

so at the time of logout in the logout page for user 1 in the referrer field it will show the link of page b but for user 2 at the logout page referrer field value will show the link of Page A. and for user 3 it will be home page.

so can any one please tell me how the referrer field value can be change dynamically based on user permission in the logout page .

Comment: in the thread group i have opted if error occur "stop thread" and used assertion under each page sampler  thats why those threads which are failing to assert are not getting counted in the next modules , for this in the logout page only 1 thread is showing always as that thread have the permission to view both those pages . so what i want to know that is there any way out so that i can send those threads also to the logout page which do not have the permission to to view page b  and also i want to know how the referer field value can be dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a possible scenario, as I don't know how you are checking the permissions of the logged users.

```
HTTP Request - Login
    Regular Expression Tester - capture an expected value to validate login
If Controller - If Login OK
    HTTP Request - Home
        Regular Expression Tester - Referrer to Home (Headers option maybe)
    HTTP Request - Page A Permission Verifier
        Regular Expression Tester - extract permission validation value
    If Controller - If user has permission to Page A
        HTTP Request - Page A
            Regular Expression Tester - Referrer to Page A (Headers option maybe)
    HTTP Request - Page B Permission Verifier
        Regular Expression Tester - extract permission validation value
    If Controller - If user has permission to Page B
        HTTP Request - Page B
            Regular Expression Tester - Referrer to Page B (Headers option maybe)
    Http Request - Logout
        HTTP Header Manager - Referrer: ${referrer}
```